Error calling RegisterAgent, code = DeadlineExceeded while booting GCP VM
14 of my VMs weren't booted properly, here are logs from one VM
WARNING 2024-05-17T01:37:44.888977751Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] Error calling RegisterAgent, attempt 1, retrying in 2s: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
WARNING 2024-05-17T01:38:46.890640434Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] Error calling RegisterAgent, attempt 2, retrying in 6s: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
ERROR 2024-05-17T01:39:52.891258152Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] context deadline exceeded
WARNING 2024-05-17T01:45:52.892232020Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] Error calling RegisterAgent, attempt 1, retrying in 2s: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
ERROR 2024-05-17T01:49:32.317311951Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] packages.GetPackageUpdates() error: error getting apt updates: exit status 100
ERROR 2024-05-17T01:56:30.702022088Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] packages.GetPackageUpdates() error: error getting apt updates: exit status 100
ERROR 2024-05-17T02:06:29.786448577Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] packages.GetPackageUpdates() error: error getting apt updates: exit status 100
ERROR 2024-05-17T02:16:29.379475848Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] packages.GetPackageUpdates() error: error getting apt updates: exit status 100
ERROR 2024-05-17T02:26:28.849338385Z [resource.labels.instanceId: 3727978341256079848] packages.GetPackageUpdates() error: error getting apt updates: exit status 100

What can I do to prevent such issues in the future?
Thanks in advance for help.
